# Is the movie Bridge of Spies really based on real event?

Tags: bridge-of-spies

Is the movie [Bridge of Spies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3682448/) really based on real event? Can anybody give me some kind of reference of this event in any book or Wikipedia article? I would like to confirm it myself.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for Bridge of Spies has all that you need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_of_Spies_%28film%29#Historical_accuracy. Your Google's as good as mine

Comment: http://www.historyvshollywood.com/reelfaces/bridge-of-spies/
http://www.biography.com/news/bridge-of-spies-true-story
The links above are some of many websites,which talks about Bridge of spies and the true story behind it. And pls!, next time before asking a question: do some research!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is based on real events.  However, like most "based on real events" movies, some artistic liberties were taken.  The story represented in the movie is mostly factual though.  It stems from the 1960 U-2 incident, which you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1960_U-2_incident).

To see what deviations were made and read about the historical accuracy of the movie, check [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_of_Spies_(film)#Historical_accuracy) out.